# Joining tables only if column has a value set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I will simplify the tables, but I basically have a table called `sheet`, and it can be assigned to one, or two `people`; so I have stored these in the sheet table as;

```
sheet
-----
sheet_id
value
person_1_id
person_2_id
```

I have the people table like this;

```
people
------
person_id
name
```

So I want to be able to load sheets by the ID of the person they are assigned to, and to also join onto the people table to get their name. So say I looking for `person_id: 2`

```
SELECT s.*, p.*, p2.* FROM sheet s 
JOIN people p ON s.person_1_id = p.person_id
JOIN people p2 ON s.person_2_id = p.person_id
WHERE person_1_id = 2 OR person_2_id
```

I want to return a consistent json object from the query, so returning the duplicated fields from one of the joins seems very wasteful. I only want to join on the person_id WHERE the person_id is set in sheet. It might have two people assigned, but I will only ever load the results by ONE person_id.

Something like

```
{ sheet_id: 1, value: 1000, person_id: 2, name: 'John' }
```

Id like to only join where the column in sheet has a value, if its not an integer it will be NULL.

I did consider moving this all out to have another table like sheet_to_person; but that massively complicates all the inserts and updates of the sheets as there would be two inserts needed on tables etc.

Comment: better to have a `sheet_person ( sheet_id int, person_id int )` table and join on that. It will make all queries better.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One way to do what you want is:

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM sheet s JOIN
     people p
     ON p.person_id = COALESCE(s.person_1_id, s.person_2_id);
```

In general, though, functions in the `ON` clause often kill performance.